# Receive custom intent without activity restart

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, linkify

I have a `TextView` with some linkification(twitter style):

```
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("@\\w+");
Linkify.addLinks(textView, pattern1, "my_activity://one=");
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("#\\w+");
Linkify.addLinks(textView, pattern2, "my_activity://two=");
```

Activity declared in manifest with following intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <data android:scheme="my_activity" />
</intent-filter>
```

Intent gets caught in the `onNewIntent` method of the activity but the activity gets restarted before that(I assume this is default behaviour).

Is there a way to receive such intent without restarting activity?

Comment: What is the launchMode of the activity? Post the whole <activity> tag from your manifest

Comment: sorry for the delay - launchmode was default. the problem was solved by setting launchmode to `singleInstance`(`singleTask` should work too).

Comment: Can you create an answer and accept it? Otherwise this ends up in the list of 'unanswered questions'. You shouldn't use `singleInstance`, as that is only for HOME-screen replacements. Actually, you should try `singleTop`. That should be enough for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Didn't know about the `singleInstance` nuance. Can you add your last comment as answer? I'll accept it  :)

Comment: Done. Thanks. Let me know if singleTop works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `launchMode` is the problem. You shouldn't use `singleInstance`, as that is only for HOME-screen replacements. You should try `singleTop`. That should be enough for what you are trying to do.