# How to startActivity() from BroadcastReceiver without recreating the activity?

Tags: android

I need to receive a broadcast event inside a broadcast receiver and than pass this information to an activity that is already open. How can I inform the activity from the broadcast receiver without it getting recreated?  This causes a total refresh which is not needed.

Now I could receive intent inside a broadcast receiver that is declared within the activity, but I also need to receive the intent when its in background as well, hence the main place I am processing the intents is in a separate broadcast receiver.  So I just don't know how to inform the activity that a new intent has arrived without onCreate() getting called and re-init the whole UI.

I think I need the NEW_TASK flag or it won't run.

PS: What are these insane downvotes about. What could be more relevant than how to start an activity from a broadcast receiver in such a way as not to recreate the activity.  BTW, I am going to find an answer w/wo you.  Why the bitter downvotes? I suspect it is because you know I could use an answer. Well I'll probably be posting an answer to this great question myself quite soon.

Comment: Don't worry, I didn't downvote you, but this is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225687/receive-custom-intent-without-activity-restart

Comment: No its not a duplicate, its close but not.

Comment: This question should be upvoted to show that unjustified negativity is not appreciated on this forum.

Comment: I do have one problem with my solution and that is that in onResume it does no seem to keep the bundle values that are sent over like it did before ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to recreate this activity do this:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

if don't want to recreate , just do this:

- while this activity on your task's top，`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);`
- declare the actvity in the manifest with: `android:lauchMode= "singleTask";`

Answer (score 1):

And the answer is .....

declare the Activity in the manifest with

```
  android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Still would like feedback on this answer as I notice that in onResume() the intent does not seem to carry over the values as it did before. So I cannot pull out values that I set on the intent inside the broadcast receiver ...

Update: In order to get the values from the receiver you may need to do the following inside the Activity:

```
             @Override 
     public void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
     {
         setIntent(intent);
     }
```

Comment: Answering your own questions is encouraged.

Comment: Others please upvote to show that unjustified negativity is not appreciated on this forum.

Comment: One thing I have to figure out still is how to get the bundle values to reach onResume().  it appears that they don't make it across in this mode.

Comment: Now, dont turn this into a discussion and tutoring site. Do your own study and research.

Comment: Actually there is more to the answer which I am updating